# formatting datetime in python please check the code and error

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

***please what could i possibly be doing wrong***

**df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='%Y-%m-%d')**

below is the error

**ValueError: time data 8/11/2021 doesn't match format specified**

Comment: you are note using the right format, try to use '%d/%m/%Y'

Comment: the format is not matching,format='%d/%m/%Y'

Comment: If you want to fix this you could look to the proper format or provide a sample of your 'Date' column in order for us to help.